# networking homework about TCP session

Tags: networking, tcp, network-protocols

Suppose that a TCP connection is established between hosts A and B.

a. Can A send 8 successive segments, each 1024 bytes long, to B without any ACKs received? If so state all protocol conditions required, if not explain why!

b. Is it possible that ACKs from B to A are lost and nevertheless A will not retransmit any of the 8 segments? Explain!

Hi all, i can't find the answer for this 2 questions... please if any1 knows help me

Comment: take a look at [RFC 2018](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2018)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is homework:

1. Think about the receive window
2. Think about timeouts